# How do I write a mysql query to combine data from related tables into a single summary?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble defining the data in a query for a chart. I want to summarize data from the first table and combine it with a data summary from the second table.

```
Products   - (serial_number, date) 
Warranties - (id, lookup_to_serial_number, warranty_issue)
```

What I want to do is to get the total number of products grouped by month and the total number of Warranties grouped together by month of production. It is a one product to many Warranties relationship. I can figure out how to get one or the other, but not both. The product serial number is unique but can have many Warranties on a single product.

The chart will be total products produced in a month compared to total number of Warranties on the products produced in that month. Both totals will be plotted on the same chart.

This is what I have so far :

```
select count(warr_id), prod_date
from product_t, warr_t
where prod_date is not null and serial_number = product_look
group by year(prod_date), month(prod_date)

union

select count(serial_number), prod_date
from product_t
where prod_date is not null
group by year(prod_date), month(prod_date)
```

This returns the results I'm looking for, but is there a way to differentiate between the two sets of data? I just came up with this an hour ago.

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. Just add an identifier column to the selection list. E.g.:

```
select count(warr_id), year(prod_date) AS prod_year, month(prod_date) AS prod_month, 'W' as type
from product_t, warr_t
where prod_date is not null and serial_number = product_look
group by year(prod_date), month(prod_date)

union

select count(serial_number), year(prod_date) AS prod_year, month(prod_date) AS prod_month, 'P' as type
from product_t
where prod_date is not null
group by year(prod_date), month(prod_date)
```

When you build the chart for the query use the `type` column for different series

Comment: Then you might want to mark cha's answer as correct? It is an elegant solution!

Comment: @cha You probably want to change the `prod_date` in the select list, to `year(prod_date) AS prod_year, month(prod_date) AS prod_month`. MySQL allows what you wrote but it's not best practice, as you'll get a semi-random result for `prod_date`.

Comment: @ypercube: thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the answer. The reason I left as `prod_date` was that it was in the original question